# Change background height that fits with the device resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with responsive image that acts as a cover background.

On the bottom area of that image I have arrow down, so the user will know that under that image, there are divs with a content.

The background image has resolution: width 1920px and height 1000px.

When I view the page with desktop Full HD resolution, the height of the image almost fits with the height on the full HD monitor, but if I check the page with laptop that has height about 768px I have to scroll the page to see the rest of the image.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="image fitbg"></div>


.image {
   background-image:url("path_of_the_image");
   height:1000px;
}

.fitbg {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

How can I set the height of the image to be exact with the height of the device?

So, if the height of the device is 1000px, the height of the image will be 1000px, but if the device resolution has height 800px, the image will be cropped from the bottom and the resolution to be set 800px.

I saw these tricks from couple of websites, they use Javascript or the JavaScript library - jQuery, but I cannot understand how they calculate that.

I've notice when I resize my browser the height of their background image is always changing, so that image always stays to the bottom of the screen.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Here's live link that has this trick, so it will be easily understand to see what I'm trying to achieve.

http://next-dc.com/work/jack-daniels-holiday-songs/

Comment: Change the `background-position` to `center bottom`..?

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't do what I want. When I scroll down it shows the rest of the image. The whole idea is to change automatically the height, so when I resize the browser or view on smaller resolution, the image will be cropped from the bottom.

Comment: Well you have a fixed height of 1000px so its of course going to need scrolling on smaller screens. You should adjust the height of the div to be 100% of the viewport using JavaScript, on resize. Or, depending on your browser support requirements, use `vh` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider setting your height of the element in CSS to `100vh`, which would mean 100% of the available viewport height and wouldn't require any Javascript, [assuming that your browser supports the viewport-based units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) :

```
.image {
   background-image:url("path_of_the_image");
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

You can see a [live example of what this might look like here](http://jsbin.com/wuceba/edit?css,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Hi, Rion. I've checked your solution and it works great. It's not exactly like the link that I've posted, it's different approach, but it works fine. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to scroll, you could do:

```
.image {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rion Williams said you can do it by css 100vh height, or if you want better backward compatibility (Android browser older than 4.3 wont render it properly, as IE below 9) you can use javascript (example with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.image').height( $(window).height() )
})
```

If you use CSS solution you shall create fallback (min-height: 240px) so it will render at least at 240px when no vh height support.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2 ways. I'm try to explain both of them.

**First**
you can use Css Media query to do this, with Media Query You can change css by device with. Hare is a link for beginners : [Media Query](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Example:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
  .image {
   background-image:url("path_of_the_image");
   height:1000px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .image {
   background-image:url("path_of_the_image");
   height:768px;
}
}
```

**Second**
You can catch device width and change CSS with JQuery also
hare is a simple example, you can change it with your own.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //When Window resize or you open page with small screen, wthis code detect size and do someting
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.resize(function resize() { 
                              // 1000 -is a pixel
        if ($window.width() > 1000) {
            //do something, you can remove or add CSS class
        }
        if ($window.width() > 768) {
    //do something, you can remove or add CSS class
        }

    }).trigger('resize');
});
```